# MySQL query to group by and use distinct row

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I have a table formatted as follows:

```
 mysql> select pattern,trunks,cost from sms_prices where pattern=1;
 +---------+--------------+-------+
 | pattern | trunks       | cost  |
 +---------+--------------+-------+
 | 1       | Vitelity     | 0.099 |
 | 1       | Plivo        | 0.012 |
 | 1       | Twilio       | 0.012 |
 +---------+--------------+-------+
 3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

My question is:

Considering this table has another 700+ entries with 3-4 entries for same pattern, how do I select DISTINCT(pattern) ordering by cost, ASC?

I tried this:

```
 mysql> select DISTINCT pattern,cost,trunks from sms_prices where pattern=1 order by cost;
 +---------+-------+--------------+
 | pattern | cost  | trunks       |
 +---------+-------+--------------+
 | 1       | 0.012 | Plivo        |
 | 1       | 0.012 | Twilio       |
 | 1       | 0.099 | Vitelity     |
 +---------+-------+--------------+
 3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

 mysql>
```

But as you can see it still gives me the same 3 results.

If i only select a single DISTINCT row, it gives me a single entry:

```
 mysql> select DISTINCT pattern from sms_prices where pattern=1 order by cost;
 +---------+
 | pattern |
 +---------+
 | 1       |
 +---------+
 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But I don't know which entry this is, so the result is useless.

Please help with a query that would return a single result per `pattern`, with the smallest `cost`

Thanks!

Comment: What is the "ideal" result you are looking for?

Comment: a list of distinct patterns (no duplicates) - along with trunks where the cost is the smallest.  For example, i have the 3 entries for pattern 1 , i would like to see trunks "Plivo" for this. When this expands (if i remove the where pattern=1) , i'll have similar cases for pattern "44" where there are like 5 different entries, all with different cost. So i'm looking to obtain a list of distinct prefixes with trunks info, having the least cost .

Comment: So just return the lowest trunk value for each pattern. Correct?

Comment: lowest "cost" value actually

Comment: the result would be pattern, cost, trunks

Comment: Sorry just noticed it was MySQL (looking at sql tag) I know how to do it in SQL if it helps.

Comment: how do you do it in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this may not be what you wanted but:

```
SELECT pattern, cost, trunks 
FROM sms_prices 
WHERE cost = (select min(cost) from sms_prices where pattern = 1)
GROUP BY pattern;
```

Regards

Comment: How do I do that for all the entries in the table (which would be without any where pattern=.. constraint) ?

Comment: got it:   SELECT pattern, cost, trunks  FROM sms_prices AS OT WHERE cost = (select min(cost) from sms_prices as IT where OT.pattern=IT.pattern ) GROUP BY pattern;

Answer (score 0):

Won't this work?

```
select pattern, min(cost) mincost
from sms_prices 
where whatever
group by pattern
```

Comment: select pattern, min(cost) mincost,trunks from sms_prices  where pattern=1 group by pattern;  --This returns pattern = 1, mincost=0.012 and trunks='Vitelity'  when actually the trunks should be 'Plivo' or 'Twilio' (which have 0.012 , which is smaller than 0.099 -- cost for Vitelity)

Comment: this is the query: SELECT pattern, MIN(cost),cost AS mincost, trunks FROM sms_prices where pattern=1 GROUP BY pattern ORDER BY MIN(cost); and this is the result:  1  | 0.012 | 0.099 | Vitelity ... Its taking the smallest cost (which is Plivo) and using it with Vitelity -- see the cost vs mincost columns

Answer (score 0):

SELECT pattern, cost, trunks  FROM sms_prices  AS OT WHERE cost = (select min(cost) from sms_prices as IT where OT.pattern=IT.pattern ) GROUP BY pattern;

Comment: I think this will end up doing the inner query once for each value of pattern, which might not be the most efficient solution.